# What is the poisson distribution?

Tags: poisson-distribution

So take this example.

The number of ice creams sold per hour from Mr Fishy’s van is observed
to be a Poisson random variable with parameter λ = 8. Each ice cream
costs two pounds but Mr Fishy has to pay five pounds per hour for the
pitch. What is the variance of his hourly profit?

Now I think this is a perfect example to illustrate how badly I understand the poisson distribution. I took λ = 8 and multiplied it by 2. Then took away £5 to get £11. It was wrong.

Can someone please explain where I went wrong?

Comment: By the rules of the variance you have to square coefficients and drop additive constants. Try to formally define the hourly profit as a random variable, and then compute the variance using its [basic properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Addition_and_multiplication_by_a_constant) and the variance of the Poisson distribution.

Comment: So, Var(2Y-5) = 4Var(Y) = 32. Gotcha thx